# Queries containing ORDER BY and LIMIT started to work slowly

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a legacy system that uses `Posgresql 9.6` and `Ubuntu 16.04`. Everything was fine several days ago even with standard Postgresql settings. I dumped a database with the compression option (maximum compression level -Z 9) in order to have a smaller size (`pg_dump --compress=9 database_name > database_name.sql`). After that I got a lot of problems. Some queries for certain tables started to be executed very slow. Queries for other tables work fine.

Here are the tables that I have issues with.

```
isbns:
id (integer)
value (string), index b-tree
type (string)



books:
id (integer)
isbn (string), index b-tree
...
(total 32 columns)



isbns_statistics:
id (integer)
average_price (float)
average_rating (integer)
isbn_id (foreign key)
...
(total 17 columns)
```

These tables contain 1 400 000 rows each.

Basically I used the following query and it worked well:

```
(1) SELECT * FROM ISBNS JOIN BOOKS ON BOOKS.ISBN = ISBN.VALUE JOIN ISBNS_STATISTICS ON ISBNS_STATISTICS.ISBN_ID = ISBNS.ID ORDER BY ISBNS.VALUE LIMIT 100;
```

But after I made the dump it started to be executed extremely slow. I'm not sure whether it's because of the dump, but before the dump everything worked well. This query also works well:

```
SELECT * FROM ISBNS JOIN BOOKS ON BOOKS.ISBN = ISBN.VALUE JOIN ISBNS_STATISTICS ON ISBNS_STATISTICS.ISBN_ID = ISBNS.ID LIMIT 100;
```

This query is executed quickly too:

```
SELECT * FROM ISBNS JOIN BOOKS ON BOOKS.ISBN = ISBN.VALUE ORDER BY ISBNS.VALUE LIMIT 100;
```

I changed performance settings (for instance, increased `shared_buffer`), but it didn't increase speed too much.

I've read that queries containing LIMIT and ORDER BY work very slow, but if I make such queries to other tables it works fine.

Here is the query plan for query (1):

```
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1048379.37..1048428.33 rows=100 width=498) (actual time=5264.193..5264.444 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=40250 read=332472, temp read=16699 written=28392
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=1048379.37..2291557.51 rows=2539360 width=498) (actual time=5264.191..5264.436 rows=100 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: ((books.isbn)::text = (isbns.value)::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=40250 read=332472, temp read=16699 written=28392
         ->  Index Scan using books_isbn_key on books  (cost=0.43..1205494.88 rows=1386114 width=333) (actual time=0.020..0.150 rows=100 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=103
         ->  Materialize  (cost=1042333.77..1055199.75 rows=2573197 width=155) (actual time=5263.901..5263.960 rows=100 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=40147 read=332472, temp read=16699 written=28392
               ->  Sort  (cost=1042333.77..1048766.76 rows=2573197 width=155) (actual time=5263.895..5263.949 rows=100 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: isbns.value
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 136864kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=40147 read=332472, temp read=16699 written=28392
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=55734.14..566061.44 rows=2573197 width=155) (actual time=403.962..1994.884 rows=1404582 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (isbns_statistics.isbn_id = isbns.id)
                           Buffers: shared hit=40147 read=332472, temp read=11281 written=11279
                           ->  Seq Scan on isbns_statistics  (cost=0.00..385193.97 rows=2573197 width=120) (actual time=0.024..779.717 rows=1404582 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=26990 read=332472
                           ->  Hash  (cost=27202.84..27202.84 rows=1404584 width=35) (actual time=402.431..402.431 rows=1404584 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1048576  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 51393kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=13157, temp written=4363
                                 ->  Seq Scan on isbns  (cost=0.00..27202.84 rows=1404584 width=35) (actual time=0.027..152.568 rows=1404584 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=13157
 Planning time: 1.160 ms
 Execution time: 5279.983 ms
(25 rows)
```

So, the questions are:

1. Why everything worked well and started to work slowly?
2. Why similar queries to other tables are still executed quickly?

Comment: This is normal; see the many other questions about queries with`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` getting a bad plan. You can force the correct plan with `ORDER BY ISBNS.VALUE NULLS FIRST` or similar. I can't get excited about a problem with such an outdated version.

Comment: I've seen the questions. But the answers don't explain why I never faced the problem before. Even now similar queries to other tables are executed quickly.

Comment: If I join 2 tables, then the query is executed pretty quickly. The problem occurs if i join three tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of broken indexes. Index for the foreign key in the `isbns_statistics` table was somehow removed during the dump. This is why there was sequential scan:

```
 ->  Seq Scan on isbns_statistics  (cost=0.00..385193.97 rows=2573197 width=120) (actual time=0.024..779.717 rows=1404582 loops=1)
                                     Buffers: shared hit=26990 read=332472
```

I restored the index for the foreign key `isbn_id` and everything is fine now.